# Phonegap android open external link issue

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

i have application in phone gap android,i m trying to open external mp3 URL in android but have issue in open mp3 URL.

All other links were open well but only mp3 URL was not open .

```
<a href="http://audio.ibeat.org/content/p1rj1s/p1rj1s_-_rockGuitar.mp3">Mp3 file</a>
```

i don't know what wrong here i have done ,is there any permission or anything else need to add.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? Do you just embed the link in your view and expect the mp3 to play?

Comment: i m trying to open above URL .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use InAppbrowser in phonegap**

```
var ref = window.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

- ref: reference to the InAppBrowser window (InAppBrowser)
- url: the URL to load (String). Call encodeURI() on this if you have
  Unicode characters in your URL.
- target: the target to load the URL in (String) (Optional, Default:
  "_self")